# In magento2 advanced reporting "Products added to wishlist" is not showing "wishlist_item" table record... Is this correct or any sync issue

Tags: magento2, addtowishlist, advanced-reporting

Where we need to check if correct data is loaded in the advanced reporting wishlist items... There is a mismatch between advanced reporting "Products added to wishlist" and wishlist_item table in database

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? Having the same issue, Advanced Reporting data is off